# Getting file url from XML file with Python

Tags: python, xml, screen-scraping, xlink

I'm trying to get a link from XML document I haven't worked with XML before but viewing the XML tree, the element: 
with xlink:href attribute

```
<media xlink:href="pone.0096102.s003.docx">
<caption>
<p>Click here for additional data file.</p>
</caption>
</media>
```

My Problem is the link isn't working or maybe I don't know xlink:href work. I want to use python `requests` to download the file.

Comment: Is your target output `pone.0096102.s003.docx`?

Comment: Yes, My objective is to download the file.

Comment: The output is just the name of the file; downloading it is a totally different matter.

Comment: I can I Identify the full path to the file? like I said I'm working with XML for the first time.

Comment: That's yet another matter :) What's the url you are working with?

Comment: I have figured something out. The XML file has something like a unique Identifier, which when I googled matched the article, so I think I will look for a way to join the article id with the file name and other url path.

Comment: I will post my findings here when it works.